# Switch Statement with user input

Tags: php, switch-statement

as a heads up I'm new at coding.

I'm trying to make a switch statement that will give the user the number that they have inputted into its proper roman number (only numbers from 1-10).

```
<form action="#" method="post">
Type a number from 1-10. <input type="text" name="num"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php

switch (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //$num = (int)$_POST["num"];
    case 1:
        echo "I";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "II";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "III";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "IV";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo "V";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo "VI";
        break;
    case 7:
        echo "VII";
        break;
    case 8:
        echo "VIII";
        break;
    case 9:
        echo "IX";
        break;
    case 10:
        echo "X";
        break;
}


?>
```

Currently, this is what I have but I don't know of a way to get the switch statement to use the number that was provided by the user. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `isset($_POST['submit'])` [returns `true` or `false`](http://www.php.net/isset). You want to test that before your `switch` (though testing for `$_POST['num']` would make a bit more sense) and then use `switch($_POST['num'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` that the user will enter a number in it has a `name` attribute of `'num'`, so to get what the user has entered, you'll use `$_POST['num']`.

```
// if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $num = (int) $_POST['num'];
  switch($num) {
    case 1:
        echo "I";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "II";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "III";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "IV";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo "V";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo "VI";
        break;
    case 7:
        echo "VII";
        break;
    case 8:
        echo "VIII";
        break;
    case 9:
        echo "IX";
        break;
    case 10:
        echo "X";
        break;
    default:
        echo 'wrong number or you probably entered a number less than 1 or higher than 10';
  }
}
```

Comment: -ths thank you so much. This helped out. Didn't know that isset had to be before the switch.

Comment: @CholoBoy glad I managed to help you. The `isset` function is mostly used when checking for form submission, [learn more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
$input = $_POST['num'];
if($input){
    switch($input) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['num']` should contain the number not `$_POST['submit']`

Answer (score 0):

First you make sure you have a something
**Notice** I am using $_POST['**num**']

```
$num = $_POST['num'] ?? 0;
```

Now you check

```
switch($num){
   case 1:
     echo 'I';
     break;
   case 2:
     echo 'II';
     break;

... 
...
```

I would do it a bit differently, and even that is not the most efficiet transformation.

```
echo (([1=>'I', 2=>'II',3=>'III',....,9=>'IX'])[$_POST['num']]) ?? '';
```

Comment: But what if the OP is running `PHP` < 7 ? the `null coalesce operator`  will not be recognized, as the `??` isn't a valid syntax.

Comment: @ths that would be sad indeed,

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_POST['submit'])` returns a boolean, which is not the integer in the range 1-10 that your `switch` statement expects. You probably meant to use `$_POST['num']`.

An array is a more compact way to encapsulate your logic instead of a long and potentially error-prone switch statement. Each array index maps to a numeral as follows:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
Type a number from 1-10. <input type="text" name="num">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

$numerals = ['', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X'];

if (isset($_POST['num'])) {
    echo isset($numerals[$_POST['num']]) ? $numerals[$_POST['num']] : "error";
}

?>
```